# How to handle onScanFailed while scanning?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am scanning BLE beacons by using following code.

```
protected void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable, Context applicationContext) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Scanning start " + type);
    bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        if (mLEScanner == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("BT le scanner not available");
        settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(
                ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
        filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>(1);
    }
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "In scanLeDevice " + type + ", enable: " + enable);
        if (enable) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Log.i(TAG, "mLEScanner startScan called");
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            } else {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            } else {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In My `Activity`, I am using fragments & I call (In `Fragment`'s `onResume()` method) this method whenever the first fragment is shown. The scanning works fine but if I switch fragments 4-5 times the `ScanCallback`'s `onScanFailed` method is called with error code 1 which means *SCAN_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED*
*Fails to start scan as BLE scan with the same settings is already started by the app.*

I see this issue only in devices with OS version 7.0 & above.

I can do 2 things here. First is that I can make sure the `onScanFailed()` is not called.
Second, restart the scanning by again calling same `scanLeDevice()` method in `onScanFailed()`.

I tried the second way but still getting the same error. The first one I couldn't.

**EDIT**
I checked more, in some cases, if it fails then it still able to scan the beacons but not always. This is creating more difficulties.

Please let me know if anyone has any solution.

Comment: I had the same issue, my problem was that I had reference to `mLEScanner` in 2 seperate places in my code and I resumed scanning when `MyActivity.onResume()` was called on both of them. So one actually started scanning and the second gave me exact same error as u are having. Solution of course was not to start scanning in those 2 places simultaneously. Your EDIT is kind of telling me u have the same issue - second scan fails so u see the fail error, but in the meantime u see the 1st scanning is happening and u think it working even with error

Comment: I found something which is working for now. But can you tell me how did you solve it?

Comment: I had two instances of `mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();` in 2 different classes and `onResume` method I made them both to start scanning again on accident of course. So it was an easy fix for me - inside onResume I just chose what scanner to turn on and it was working fine. In your situation it kind of feels like you forgot to turn off scanner in one of your fragments. Maybe your scanner turn off code is in fragments `onDestroy` method but you are adding fragments using `add` instead of `replace` so destructor never gets called. Hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: I tried calling startScan again in case of failure, but it didn't work for me. And I did try by stopping scan for other fragments but again didn't work.

Comment: You should open Android Monitor and check if scanning actually stopped when you think it should have stopped if you are running app on ur mobile device connected with usb.  And posting some extra code might help as well in case scanning actually stops. In my case when I scan for devices this Android Monitor section gets flooded with stuff like `D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=00:1F:C4:56:0B:2C, mScanRecord=ScanRecord...`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to overcome this problem. Now, whenever I see `onFailed()` is called I start a thread (using `Handler`) which reloads the whole fragment again after some interval. And if the scan restarts automatically I remove all the callbacks.

So far this solution seems to be working fine.

Ideally, I should limit the no of start & stop scan calls, but it was already implemented that way, so I had to try this way only.